# Корректная остановка потока в OmniThreadLibrary

Tags: delphi, omnithreadlibrary

Создал `Task` с использованием библиотеки `OmniThreadLibrary`. При вызове метода `FTask.Terminate` - работа останавливается, но будет это корректным?

Может есть какие то другие пути скажем выполнить команду `Terminate` и проверить в потоке `if Terminated then Exit`?

```
TSomeClass = Class
Private 
 FEventMonitor: TOmniEventMonitor;
 FTask: IOmniTaskControl;
public 
  procedure Start;
  procedure Stop;
End;

Constructor TSomeClass.Create;
Begin
    FEventMonitor := TOmniEventMonitor.Create(Nil);
End;

procedure TSomeClass.Start;
var 
   Task: IOmniTaskControl;
begin
   Task := CreateTask(SomeProc, 'Some task');
   FTask := FEventMonitor.Monitor(Task).Run;
end;

procedure TSomeClass.Stop;
begin
   If Assigned(FTask) Then
     FTask.Terminate(2000);
end;

Procedure TSomeClass.SomeProc(Сonst Task: IOmniTask);
begin
    ....
end;
```

Comment: В обычных потоках (`TThread`) метод `Terminate` устанавливает флаг `Terminated` и больше ничего не делает. По этому там нужно в потоке проверять этот флаг самостоятельно. Как в `OmniThreadLibrary` не знаю, обратитесь к документации или посмотрите исходники, если есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данной библиотеке можно отправить "сигнал" (FTask.CancellationToken.Signal) остановки и внутри проверить установлен данный сигнал или нет следующим образом:

```
Procedure TSomeClass.SomeProc(Сonst Task: IOmniTask);
begin
    ...
    if Task.CancellationToken.IsSignalled then
        Exit;
    ...
end;

procedure Stop;
begin
  If Assigned(FTask) Then
     FTask.CancellationToken.Signal;
end;
```